# How Default page is executing in my asp.net project first

Tags: asp.net

May be the below question is a simple question but I want to understant

In my asp.net web project how the default page is first executing at the time of debugging.  I have not set the default page as start page and web.config also I have not done any setting for default page.

Thanks,
Saroj

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is a setting in IIS file called applicationhost.config

In this it has section

```
<system.webServer>
```

...

And default document hierarchy as below

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
    <files>
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="index.html" />
        <add value="iisstart.htm" />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

So answer for your question where does 'default.aspx' is written points to applicationhost.config > system.webServer section > defaultDocument list